# Location.watchPositionAsync is not periodically updating

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, geolocation

I'm using the expo-location sensor to get updates on an Android device location.

I'm using the `Location.watchPositionAsync(options, callback)` function in particular.

I'm trying to log the values of the location every 500 milliseconds, using the `timeInterval` property.

However, with my current code, it only logs the value of my location to the terminal when I hit Ctrl+S on VSCode. I want the location to update automatically every 500 milliseconds.

The documentation for the library can be found here: [Expo Geolocation Library](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location/#locationwatchpositionasyncoptions-callback)

My code is as follows:

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Platform, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

export default function App() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {( async () => {

      const locationSubscription = await Location.watchPositionAsync({
            accuracy: Location.Accuracy.High,
            timeInterval: 500,
            // distanceInterval: 1,
      }, (location) => {
        setLocation(location)
        console.log('New location update: ' + location.coords.latitude + ', ' + location.coords.longitude)
      })
    
    return () => locationSubscription.remove()
  })()}, [])

  let text = 'Waiting..';
  if (errorMsg) {
    text = errorMsg;
  } else if (location) {
    text = JSON.stringify(location);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>Hi</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 20,
  },
  paragraph: {
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: Has the location changed?

Comment: Yes, it changes, but only when I keep clicking Ctrl+S on VSCode. I want it to refresh automatically every 500 milliseconds (or every second)